# Copiar archivos a sus respectivas carpetas y subcarpetas

Tags: java

tengo este código de java en el cual cree una interfaz gráfica que copia de una carpeta a otra, ahora lo que necesito es que cuando yo copie una carpeta en especifico esta introduzca los archivos en sus respectivas subcarpetas. Como puedo hacerlo? les dejo lo que logre hasta ahora.Gracias de antemano.

```
import com.sun.javafx.logging.JFRInputEvent;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class iniciar1 extends JFrame {
   JTextField origenFileTextField;
   JTextField destinoFileTextField;

public iniciar1() throws HeadlessException {
    setTitle("Transferir Archivos");
    JLabel sourceFileJLabel = new JLabel("Ruta: ");
    origenFileTextField = new JTextField();
    JButton origenFileChoserButton = new JButton("Archivos de 
  Actualizacion");
    origenFileChoserButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            jFileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            int status = jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(iniciar1.this);
            if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                String selectedFilePath = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                origenFileTextField.setText(selectedFilePath);
            }
        }
    });
    JLabel destinoFileJLabel = new JLabel("Ruta: ");
    destinoFileTextField = new JTextField();
    JButton destinoFileChoserButton = new JButton("Carpeta de Proyectos");
    destinoFileChoserButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            jFileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            int status = jFileChooser.showSaveDialog(iniciar1.this);
            if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                String selectedFilePath = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                destinoFileTextField.setText(selectedFilePath);
            }

        }
    });
    JButton botonCopiar = new JButton("Copiar");
    botonCopiar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            File origenFile = new File(origenFileTextField.getText());
            File destinoFile = new File(destinoFileTextField.getText() );
            try {
              FileUtils.copyDirectory(origenFile,destinoFile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 5, 5));
    add(sourceFileJLabel);
    add(origenFileTextField);
    add(origenFileChoserButton);
    add(destinoFileJLabel);
    add(destinoFileTextField);
    add(destinoFileChoserButton);
    add(botonCopiar);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    iniciar1 copyFile = new iniciar1();
    copyFile.setSize(400, 150);
    copyFile.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    copyFile.setVisible(true);


}
private ArrayList<File> vector = new ArrayList<File>();
public ArrayList<File> listarTodo(File dir)
{
    vector.clear();
    listarT(dir);
    return vector;
}
private void listarT(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        vector.add(dir);
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
            listarT(new File(dir, children[i]));

    } else
        vector.add(dir);
}
private void copiarDirectorio(File directorio, String dirDestino) {
    String dirNombre = directorio.getName();
    File archDestino = new File(dirDestino + dirNombre);
    String rootFolder = "C:\\";



    archDestino.mkdir();
    File [] porCopiar = directorio.listFiles();
    directorio.toPath();

    for(File file : porCopiar) {
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            copiarDirectorio(file, archDestino.getAbsolutePath() + "/");
        }
         else {
            copiarDirectorio(file, archDestino.getAbsolutePath() + "/");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar MS-DOS.

Código mucho mas sencillo y menos dolores de cabeza:

    `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("move "C:\\Carpeta1" "C:\\Carpeta2");`

En este caso movería la "Carpeta1" y todo su contenido, dentro de la "Carpeta2"

Comment: Puedes usar la librería de Apache `commons-io` y su [método para copiar directorios](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory-java.io.File-java.io.File-)